# How to use other file extensions in php-cs-fixer, for example .ctp?

Tags: cakephp, php-cs-fixer

How to use other file extensions in php-cs-fixer, for example cakephp template .ctp files ?

I have trying this code:

```
<?php
$finder = PhpCsFixer\Finder::create()
    ->notPath('bootstrap/cache')
    ->notPath('storage')
    ->notPath('vendor')
    ->in(__DIR__)
    ->name('*.php') // <===== *.ctp
    ->notName('*.blade.php')
    ->ignoreDotFiles(true)
    ->ignoreVCS(true)
;

return PhpCsFixer\Config::create()
    ->setRules(array(
        '@Symfony' => true,
        'binary_operator_spaces' => ['align_double_arrow' => false],
        'array_syntax' => ['syntax' => 'short'],
        'linebreak_after_opening_tag' => true,
        'not_operator_with_successor_space' => true,
        'ordered_imports' => true,
        'phpdoc_order' => true,
    ))
    ->setFinder($finder)
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Thing is, that with original way of running the PHP CS Fixer, you have path finder configured once in config file, and then you pass the path also as CLI argument.
As a result - you have fully defined finder in config, which got later overwritten by CLI argument, also you got a message:

```
Paths from configuration file have been overridden by paths provided as command arguments.
```

Solution is to:
- provide a path only in config file
- provide a path only as CLI argument
- provide a path in both places (ex, in config `plugins`, while as CLI argument `plugins/subdir` (as passing exactly same value doesn't really make sense...), but then also provide `--path-mode=intersection` parameter, to not override the path, but take common part of paths (one in config, one as CLI arg)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50908446/891636 for noob friendly explanation of this answer

Answer (score -2):

Very important do not use path argument in terminal command
Example:

```
php-cs-fixer fix test/global.php
```

cs fixer use path from command argument, NOT finder

Just run with

```
php-cs-fixer fix
```

It is simple, but you can skip it by inattention