# Getting Non PHP File Extensions in Symfony Finder / PHP-CS-Fixer

Tags: php, symfony, php-cs-fixer

Struggling with adding non php extensions to my finder. Done a long google search but came up blank. Found this but couldn't quite understand: [How to use other file extensions in php-cs-fixer, for example .ctp?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48967493/891636)

This is what I have:

```
<?php
$finder = PhpCsFixer\Finder::create()
    ->notPath('path/to/some/file.inc')
    ->notPath('path/to/some/file.class')
    ->in(__DIR__)
    ->name('*.php')
    ->name('*.inc')
    ->name('*.class');

    return PhpCsFixer\Config::create()
        ->setRules(
            array(
                'Rule 1' => true,
                ...
                'Rule n' => true,
            )
        )
    ->setFinder($finder);
```

I will like it to work on the *.inc and *.class files but it only seems to be picking the *.php files.

Any clues to what I may have missed?

**PS**

I forgot to add that trying a single `->name('/(\.php|\.inc|\.class)$/');` makes no difference. It still only picks *.php files.

Also, instead of voting me down without explanation, please give me a definitive answer ... is there something I am doing wrongly? If so, point me to this.

Comment: Did you try to pass a Regex instead call 3 times `->name()` . May be the finder just keep the first  call to name method ? The [method accepts pattern](https://api.symfony.com/4.1/Symfony/Component/Finder/Finder.html#method_name) test it to see...

Comment: @Smaïne please see updated query. I had already tested a pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is not fully described, can't reproduce.

```
ker@dus:~/github/PHP-CS-Fixer λ cat .php_cs.dist 
<?php

$finder = PhpCsFixer\Finder::create()
    ->in(__DIR__ . '/example')
    ->name('*.inc')
;

return PhpCsFixer\Config::create()
    ->setRules([
        '@Symfony' => true,
    ])
    ->setFinder($finder)
;
```

---

```
ker@dus:~/github/PHP-CS-Fixer λ ls -al example/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  2 keradus keradus 4096 cze 18 13:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 keradus keradus 4096 cze 18 10:20 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 keradus keradus 1550 cze 17 12:00 FileReader.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 keradus keradus 1507 cze 18 13:20 FileRemoval.inc
```

---

```
ker@dus:~/github/PHP-CS-Fixer λ php php-cs-fixer fix -vv --dry-run --diff --diff-format=udiff
Loaded config default from "/home/keradus/github/PHP-CS-Fixer/.php_cs.dist".
.F
Legend: ?-unknown, I-invalid file syntax, file ignored, S-Skipped, .-no changes, F-fixed, E-error
   1) example/FileRemoval.inc (braces)
      ---------- begin diff ----------
--- Original
+++ New
@@ -29,7 +29,8 @@
      */
     private $files = [];

-    public function __construct() {
+    public function __construct()
+    {
         register_shutdown_function([$this, 'clean']);
     }


      ----------- end diff -----------


Checked all files in 0.027 seconds, 12.000 MB memory used
```

`*.inc` file was fixed

## ** EDIT BY OP **

After some great support on the project gitter page: https://gitter.im/PHP-CS-Fixer/Lobby, it turns out the issue was that the way I was calling things on the command line was overwriting the path information in my config file.

A clue was the CLI message that read `Paths from configuration file have been overridden by paths provided as command arguments`.

My original command was...

`php php-cs-fixer fix /path/to/project/folder --config /path/to/config/file/.php_cs.dist`

Two options that should have been used:

1. Skip the `/path/to/project/folder`
   Correct command = `php php-cs-fixer fix --config /path/to/config/file/.php_cs.dist`. According to the devs, this could have a drawback in that one may not be able to run the tool with sub paths of the root project.
2. Add a `-path-mode=intersection`flag to the CLI statement to make things play nice with each other. Correct command = `php php-cs-fixer fix /path/to/project/folder --config /path/to/config/file/.php_cs.dist --path-mode=intersection`